# Strange Behaviour of Vim on New Lines

Tags: vim

I have the problem with DOS new lines (`0d 0a`), which I try to replace in `vim`. I believe to make already couple of times before, but now I am really stuck, as `vim` does not want to see the character:

1. When I try to enter it by pressing `CTRL` `V` and `CTRL` `M` to run `:%s/^M//g`, I see the error:

   `E486: Pattern not found: ^M`
2. Even when I try to replace it by hex code with `:%s/\%x0d//g`, I see the error:

   `E486: Pattern not found: \%x0d`

   I, however, can remove/replace other characters, e.g. `:%s/\%x61//g`
3. When I try `:%s/\n/\r/g`, nothing happens
4. When I try to remove it in two steps with `:%s/\n/XXX/g` followed by `:%s/XXX//g`, it goes away. However, in case I use `:%s/XXX/\r/g` on the second step, vim inserts `0d 0a` back instead of expected `0a`

Therefore, question: is there a way to convert all new lines to `0a` in `vim`? Why does hex replacement not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `:help 'fileformat'`.

```
:set ff=unix
:w
```

should do it.

This is matching newlines, by the way:

```
:%s/\n/\r/
```

But it's replacing newlines with newlines, and when you
write the buffer vim will use whatever line ending is
determined by 'fileformat'.